# All past day IIS log files are empty

Tags: windows, iis, logging, iis-8

In IIS8, only the currently active log file has data in it. All other log files show 0kb. Has anyone run into this before? The disk these are written to has > 60GB free

[image: Log settings]

[image: Log files]

Answer (score 0):

0K log file can happen if your router was not forwarding correctly the traffic to the server, thus no traffic. (or if the internet dropped)

As such it's not a IIS bug, but a upstream's bug usually.

Comment: No, this is a production server. I have a year's worth of 0KB log files. Only the currently active log file has data. The file 2.3MB file from 12/22 in the screenshot is now 0KB and the 12/23 file has data.